# how to link to access database file in created .exe file with c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I want to create setup file for my C# project. I use access 2010 with my project. I link to database file in every form of my project. This my database link

```
OleDbConnection db_con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=C:\Users\HUNAR\Desktop\Bashi Nawxoyy\Bashi Nawxoyy\bin\Debug\db_file.accdb;Jet 
OLEDB:Database Password=RTm$&9sdfZXC;Persist Security Info=True");
```

know in creation of setup file I want to config access database file in app.config file and call it in every form. Also I want to attach db file with the setup file and the setup file be able to connect to db file in every machine that i install the setup file on it?

Comment: I think you'd better use |DataDirectory| instead of defining the address this way. Source=|DataDirectory|\db_file.accdb

Comment: i use |DataDirectory|\db_file.accdb in my app.config file but it can not connect to db file?

Comment: Is your database located exactly where your application's executable file is? Otherwise you have to define the path after |DataDirectory|

Comment: @Bytes Oracle can you explain for me how i do this in detail where to put db file? how to config db file link in app.config file? how to call it in my forms? my db file db_file.accdb

Comment: I would recommend you to read the link I attached, I think it can solve your problem. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3f9608fe-03d6-4a72-ab35-ec6ca7969a05/how-to-use-appconfig-file-for-set-database-connection

Comment: i create folder called Data inside my project folder i put database file in Data folder and i use `<add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Data\\db_file.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=AAbb12;Persist Security Info=True" name="connectionString"/>` in my app.config file. konw when i open the project if i do any operation it says it can not connect to the db_file ??

Comment: can any answer and help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create .exe Setup Project  of your **Dot Net** Application which is using **MS Access DATA BASES**. then simply follow this steps. Please read this one for a moment before to proceed these steps.[Connect with MS Access Data Base in Dot net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275557/c-sharp-inserting-data-from-a-form-into-an-access-database/22140884#22140884).
When you are going to create the exe file then your data base connection string should be like this(means there should be no directory in @"Data source, Just direct put the name of your data base, because in .exe file when you add your data base file, then it is in the same directory.

```
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
     @"Data source=MyDataBase.accdb";
```

1. Right click on your solution file. *(like in Solution Explorer "Solution 'MyProject' ")*
2. Select Add -->New Project -->Other Project Types
3. Select "Setup"
4. A New project will be added named setup (*with a new tab added to
   editor as File System )*
5. Now right click on application folder -->select add -->select folder
   new folder will be added under application folder * Now Right click
   on newly added folder -->select add -->select file * Add File dialog
   will be popup
6. Select your Db file *(means from a "Browse" Button there go and select your Access Data Base )*
7. Select Setup project and build.. Now your
       installer will have your DB.

Some screen shot which will help you
[image: step1] [image: step2]