# Auto generate connection string for install database

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection, installshield

I developed an app to check stock. I made a setup to install the app too. But in my app.config file, I have a specific path for accessing the database (I am using Access)

I was wondering if I could use InstallShield to allow users to choose a path where the database can be installed?

```
<add connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Jet OlEDB:Database Password=Welkom01; Data Source= C:\Users\robert\Documents\A&amp;A Inventory\A&amp;A database1.accdb" name ="myConnection"/>
```

This is the connection string that I am currently using.

I want to be able to install the app on a server so anyone logged in can use the app.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks  guys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Install Shield I prefer u to use Advance Installer. Its also Create plugin in Ur Visual Studio. and for connection String and attachment of ur database file U should Follow this Link. Its very helpful.
[how to link to access database file in created .exe file with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358794/how-to-link-to-access-database-file-in-created-exe-file-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use this

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconnection" connectionString="server=webpc;Password=yourpassword;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DBName;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

in my case i use webpc for server name and your case you can take your server name. it may be a name or IP so first check your server name ...